# Plasma custom shortcut Alt+Ñ doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, plasma

I've defined a custom shortcut in the plasma settings (of a kubuntu 19.10 distribution) by `Alt+Ñ` (Im using a spanish distribution on the keyboard). Then if I press the hotkey nothing happens, however if I change the hotkey to some more 'universal' keys as `Alt+J` then the hotkey works as expected.

Someone knows how to fix this behavior?